# Почему не получается изменить величину шрифта?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

Есть js код

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) 
{}
else {
var a = document.getElementById("wrapper");
a.style.fontSize = "36px";
}
```

Есть html код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="css/cssfrmn.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="css/corecss.css">
  <script src="js/mnjs.js"></script>
  <script src="js/oprd.js"></script>
  <title>Core Q5</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="menu">
   <table>
    <tr><button><a href="akk.html" class="mn" id="01">9</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="msg.html" class="mn" id="02">8</a></button></tr                >
    <tr><button><a href="news.html" class="mn" id="03">7</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="publ.html" class="mn" id="04">6</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="lib.html" class="mn" id="05">5</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="targ.html" class="mn" id="06">4</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="mbq5.html" class="mn" id="07">3</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="chr.html" class="mn" id="08">2</a></button></tr>
    <tr><button><a href="pard.html" class="mn" id="09">1</a></button></tr>
    <tr><div id="reg"><button><a href="reg.html" class="mn">0</a></button></div></tr>
   </table>
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="upline">
    <button id="jmk" class="0" onclick="movhtml()"><h2>→</h2></button>
   </div>
   <div id="expl">
   <br>
   <h1>пример текста</h1>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Проблема заключается в том что код отказывается работать, говоря что у значения null нет style.

Я перепробовал несколько вариантов решения проблемы, но в итоге ничего не смог, по этому и решил обратиться к вам.
Что же мне сделать с кодом, что бы он работал так как надо?
(В полном файле текста и div-ов намного больше)

Comment: переместите скрипт перед закрытием `</body>` (в самом конце)

Answer (score 0):

Потому что во время выполнения скрипта элемент может еще не быть разобран браузером и не добавлен в дерево. Вам нужно выполнить скрипт после окочания загрузки страницы, например поместить скрипт вконец страницы

Подробнее можно узнать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-ondomcontentloaded)